# Calculate in table

Tags: jquery

I want to calculate each row in the below `table` element by using jQuery. How can I do that?

`a` and `b` have an input element and when I click 'total', the result will appear in "a+b" column.

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
$("#total").click(function(){
    var a = $(".a").val();
    var b = $(".b").val();
    var tt = a+b;
    $('.a-b').text(tt);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your markup look like?

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Can you post html code ?

Comment: $("#total").click(function(){
 var a = $(".a").val();
 var b = $(".b").val();
 var tt = a+b;
 $('.a-b').text(tt);
});

Comment: I just can do like this and I know I'm wrong

Comment: add you html and css code

Comment: do the td contain input boxes?

Comment: @ellipsis yes.<td><input/></td>

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#total").click(function(){ 
  $("#yourtable tr").each(function(i, el){ //go through each tr in table id=yourtable
     var a = $(el).find(".a").val();  //find .a in each row
     var b = $(el).find(".b").val();  //find .b in each row
     var tt = a+b;
     $(el).find('.a-b').text(tt);  //set result into .a-b of current row
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But it seems like I have to convert String to Int cause when I type 1 and 2, the result is 12

Answer (score 1):

Used input type number to avoid string concat issue.
Also checked for valid number after addition using [isNan](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) else it will assign blank value in column. You can also add error message here.

```js
$("#total").click(function() {

  $("tbody tr").each(function() {
    var a = ($(".a", this).val());
    var b = ($(".b", this).val());
    var tt = a + b;
    if (!isNaN(tt))
      $('.a-b', this).text(tt);
    else
      $('.a-b', this).text(''); //your error message if addition is invalid

  })

});
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>a+b</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="a"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="b"></td>
      <td><label class="a-b"></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="a"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="b"></td>
      <td><label class="a-b"></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="total">total</button>
```

Comment: Note that since the answer uses parseInt and this is JavaScript, it will truncate away any decimals. Otherwise nice and simple answer.

Comment: Thanks @Silwing to notice that. I have updated answer. Used input type in html.